# If $f$ is holomorphic then $\exists N$ such that $|f^n(0)|<n!n^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in a neighborhood of $0$. Prove that  $\exists N$ such that $|f^n(0)|<n!n^n$ for every $n>N$.

From $|f^{(n)}(0)|<n!n^n$ follows $\displaystyle\frac{|f^{(n)}(0)|}{n!}<n^n$ which I think suggest the idea of Taylor series.

1. $f$ holomorphic, then $f^{(n)}$ exists for every $n$. Taking the Taylor series around zero we have $\displaystyle f(z)\approx f(0)+f'(0)z+\frac{f''(0)}{2}z^2+\dots+\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$.
2. Then $\displaystyle f(n)\approx f(0)+f'(0)n+\frac{f''(0)}{2}n^2+\dots+\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}n^n$
3. Follows $\displaystyle \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}n^n\approx f(n)-f(0)-f'(0)n-\frac{f''(0)}{2}n^2-\dots-\frac{f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}n^{n-1}$
4. $\displaystyle  f^{(n)}(0)\approx \frac{n!}{n^n}\left(f(n)-f(0)-f'(0)n-\frac{f''(0)}{2}n^2-\dots-\frac{f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}n^{n-1}\right)$

The problem is I need $\left(f(n)-f(0)-f'(0)n-\frac{f''(0)}{2}n^2-\dots-\frac{f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}n^{n-1}\right)<n^{2n}$ for large enough $n$, which seems right, but I don't know a very convincing proof of that.

Comment: Looks like a job for Cauchy, perhaps

Comment: Hint: There exists $c$ such that, for every $n$, $|f^{(n)}(0)|\leqslant n!c^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sum a_nz^n$ converges on a disk of positive radius, then you know that $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$ is finite. Can you deduce the result from this?